# Update document, create new document or do nothing depending on subdocument properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```js
const OrderProductSchema = new Schema<TOrderDetailsSchema>({
  orderLimit: Number,
  productId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: true },
  amount: Number
});

/* OrderSchema correspond to a Orders collection in MongoDB. */
const OrderSchema = new Schema<TOrderSchema>({
  vendor: String,
  productsInOrder: [OrderProductSchema]
});

/* order products */
const orderProduct1 = {
  orderLimit: 5,
  productId: 'some-object-id',
  amount:  4
};

const orderProduct2 = {
  orderLimit: 3,
  productId: 'some-other-object-id',
  amount:  3
};

const orderProduct3 = {
  orderLimit: 8,
  productId: 'some-another-other-object-id',
  amount: 5
};

/* orders */
const order1 = {
  vendor: 'first-vendor',
  productsInOrder: [orderProduct1, orderProduct2, orderProduct3]
};

const order2 = {
  vendor: 'second-vendor',
  productsInOrder: [/* some not listed orderProducts */]
};
```

I have a use case where I need to:

1. find an order where subdocument `OrderProduct` with `amount` greater than or equal to `orderLimit` exists
2. if it exists do nothing
3. if it doesn't find an order subdocument `OrderProduct` with `amount` less than `orderLimit` and increase `amount` by 1
4. if there's no such order but there's an order with the same `vendor`, create a new `OrderProduct` and push it to `productsInOrder`
5. if there's no order, create new order, create `OrderProduct` and add it to array.

So when adding another `orderProduct1` to `order1`, `orderProduct1`s `amount` should increase by 1.

When adding `orderProduct2` to `order1` nothing should happen because its `amount` is equal to its `orderLimit`

When adding a new product to `order2` `OrderProduct` should be created and added to `productsInOrder` array.

I thought I can do all this if-order-limit-do-nothing-else-if-exist-update in a single aggregation but I can't figure out how to use `$merge` conditionally or if it's even possible.

So what would be the most optimal way to achieve that?

###### PS. `$merge` does not return updated document in Nodejs driver, all it returns is an empty array whether it's successfull or discarded!

##### [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aBdsICWsrdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all with a single update using the [aggregation pipeline update framework](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20aggregation%20pipeline%20allows,of%20another%20field(s).), like so:

```
const newProduct = {
  orderLimit: 3,
  productId: 'some-other-object-id',
  amount:  3
};


db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
  "vendor": "Vendor 1"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      productsInOrder: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [
              newProduct.productId,
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$productsInOrder.productId",
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          // if product exists
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$productsInOrder",
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.productId",
                          newProduct.productId
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $lt: [
                          {
                            $toInt: "$$this.amount"
                          },
                          {
                            $toInt: "$$this.orderLimit"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        amount: {
                          $sum: [
                            1,
                            {
                              $toInt: "$$this.amount"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  // do nothing
                  "$$this",
                ]
              },
              
            }
          },
          // product does not exist
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$productsInOrder",
                  []
                ]
              },
              [
                newProduct
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  upsert: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MVYmEjVsgwc)

Comment: haven't given it a field test yet but mongoplayground you provided doesn't produce correct result. It increases `amount` field for both `orderProduct`s

Comment: [fixed](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MVYmEjVsgwc)

Comment: awesome job, thank you! could you please explain how it works? I don't understand whole `$cond` part

Comment: Sure, the `$cond` checks if the product exists in the list, if not we just use `$concatArrays` to "push" the new product into the existing list, if it does exists there `$map` that iterates the array, each elements is check if it matches the condition of _id=new product id and amount < orderlimit, if the either condition is not met then the original document is "returned" by the map ( aka does not change ), if both conditions are met we just return the object but with an amount + 1.

Comment: I don't understand how boolean-expression part of `$cond` works.